# Using a VLAN in embedded linux and although a response is received no entry made in ARP table

Tags: linux, vlan, arp

I need to set up 2 VLANs, but I have this issue even with only one configured (.2) but when I set up the other VLANc (.1) it seems to work ok.

The issue is that ARP doesnt seem to work which sort of hurts all the rest of networking pretty bad.  As I looked into it more - I see that a ping to the gateway on the network for instance induces an ARP request (which seems to make sense since the GW isnt already in the table) I see the request go out on the correct VLAN tag in Tcpdump.  I further see the response come back from the gateway telling the MAC address, but the arp table stays stuck with a "(incomplete)" in the arp table.  I experience the exact same thing with another end point on the same subnet besides the GW.

Im currently just creating the VLAN with ifconfig eth0.2 172.16.110.240 netmask 255.255.255.192

/var # ping 172.16.110.241
PING 172.16.110.241 (172.16.110.241): 56 data bytes

--- 172.16.110.241 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/var # arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
172.16.110.241                   (incomplete)                              eth0.2
/var #
/var #
/var # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:E7:FF:D5:E5
inet addr:10.255.213.229  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: fe80::21a:e7ff:feff:d5e5/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:30421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:2645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:2956061 (2.8 MiB)  TX bytes:1351612 (1.2 MiB)

eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:E7:FF:D5:E5
inet addr:172.16.110.240  Bcast:172.16.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
inet6 addr: fe80::21a:e7ff:feff:d5e5/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:3369 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:180561 (176.3 KiB)  TX bytes:72348 (70.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
RX packets:784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:274294 (267.8 KiB)  TX bytes:274294 (267.8 KiB)

Comment: Ive gone in and manually added an entry for the GW and then networking seems to work fine for a bit and then something changes and it breaks again until I delete and re-add that arp entry.

Comment: Starting to wonder if there is something special about .1 - I read that I shouldnt be using it as its sometimes reserved for the system - so maybe if I use .2 and .3 they would both be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well - it turns out for me this was a land mine someone left in a configured arptables which was dropping everything which didnt go to one of my several IP addresses.